# How to export class as root module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, commonjs

I'm using TypeScript to build a Node project. When TS compiles my classes to JS, there appears to be an un-needed extra depth exported, allow me to illustrate.

**TS**

```
export class AppInfo {
    public name: string;
    public version: string;
    
    constructor(name: string, version: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

**Generated JS**

```
var AppInfo = (function () {
    function AppInfo(name, version) {
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
    }
    return AppInfo;
})();
exports.AppInfo = AppInfo;
```

So if I want to import this class, I have to do this:

```
const AppInfo = require("./AppInfo").AppInfo;

var appInfo = new AppInfo(...);
```

How do I tell TypeScript to export my classes directly? Like this:

```
exports = AppInfo;
```

Answer (score 3):

> exports = AppInfo;

Use `export =` as shown below:

```
class AppInfo {
    public name: string;
    public version: string;

    constructor(name: string, version: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
    }
}
export = AppInfo;
```

Comment: Sorry, I did try that but I get in trouble -- now TS doesn't like how I import this class/module from other local classes. Originally I was using `import {AppInfo} from "./AppInfo";`, and I also tried `import * as AppInfo from "./AppInfo";`, but either way I get the error: `TS2497: Module '"c:/.../AppInfo"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct`

Comment: @JoshM. maybe you're looking for `export default AppInfo` then `import AppInfo from "./AppInfo";`? That will still create a named export called "default" though.

Comment: Hmm, that generates the following JS: `exports.AppInfo = AppInfo;
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    exports.default = AppInfo;`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
exports.AppInfo = AppInfo;
```

use

```
module.exports = AppInfo;
```

Comment: Yes, but TypeScript is generating the `exports` statement, not me.

Answer (score 0):

What I found that works is this:

```
class AppInfo {
    public name: string;
    public version: string;
    constructor(name: string, version: string) {
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
    }
}

namespace AppInfo {}
export = AppInfo
```

This seems to support both local usage and external usage.